# why is the text being appended several times

Tags: jquery, html

I try to add functionality to allow user to edit the values of a table, either by adding/deleting/modifying the table and its data.

I've managed to get it to do what I want but the text I want to append gets appended 4 times and I'm not wise enough to understand why.

I've set up demo here http://jsfiddle.net/a973/CWQh9/1

and this is the code fired

```
$('#saveBtn').live("click", function(){
    var txt = $("#compName").val();
    var txt2 = $("#orgnr").val();

    $(".itms").fadeOut("normal", function() {
            $(this).remove();

            $('#comp').append(txt);
            $('#orgn').append(txt2);
            $('#nextLast').append('<a href="#">change</a>')
            $('#lastTd').append("<a href='#'>erase</a>");

    });
```

Can anyone help me get rid of the 3 extra instances of texts?

The  final result will only be used for demoing/prototype purposes.

Comment: Try create this as a JSFiddle

Comment: Should probably convert live() to on() while you're at it. Looks like an effortless direct swap in this case.

Comment: @Rick Donohoe, I've included a jsfiddle link in the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the handler is called for each of your `".itms"`. So each time the `append()` function is called.

I added what you were asking for in the comments below.

**New solution: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CWQh9/11/)**

Do it like that:

```
$('#saveBtn').live("click", function () {
    var txt = $("#compName").val();
    var txt2 = $("#orgnr").val();
    //$('#compName, #orgnr, #saveBtn, #cncl').remove();

    setTimeout( function() {
        $('#comp').append(txt);
    $('#orgn').append(txt2);
    $('#nextLast').append('<a href="#">change</a>')
    $('#lastTd').append("<a href='#'>erase</a>");
    }, 500);

    $(".itms").fadeOut("normal", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
    $('#raden').effect("highlight", {}, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `$('.itms')` selector is matching four elements on the page. Therefore the callback function is being called four times. That means the call to append is happening four times.

Answer (score 1):

Move these four lines outside of the fadeOut call:

```
$('#comp').append(txt);
$('#orgn').append(txt2);
$('#nextLast').append('<a href="#">change</a>')
$('#lastTd').append("<a href='#'>erase</a>");
```

So you get this:

```
$('#saveBtn').live("click", function () {
    var txt = $("#compName").val();
    var txt2 = $("#orgnr").val();
    $('#comp').append(txt);
    $('#orgn').append(txt2);
    $('#nextLast').append('<a href="#">change</a>')
    $('#lastTd').append("<a href='#'>erase</a>");
    $(".itms").fadeOut("normal", function () {
        $(this).remove();
    });
})
```

Otherwise your appends are called several times, once per each `.itms`.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/CWQh9/8/)** (note that i also updated your `.live()` to `.on()` since live has been deprecated.

Comment: thanks, I've tried that but that makes the text append before the items are faded out and that is not the effect I want. Basically I just want the input fields to fade away and their values should remain as saved data, and then replace the cancel and save buttons with an erase and a modify link.

Answer (score 0):

Most probable cause is that there are four elements with the css class .itms and hence the callback fired four times. As I see the code, there are four td s which are present in the table and hence this is fired four times

Answer (score 0):

Because there are multiple elements that match your selector, the function gets called multiple times. Try doing it on a clicked element.

```
 $(".itms").click().fadeOut("normal", function() {

            $(this).remove();

            $('#comp').append(txt);
            $('#orgn').append(txt2);
            $('#nextLast').append('<a href="#">change</a>')
            $('#lastTd').append("<a href='#'>erase</a>");


    });
```